# Column isn't expanding

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a widget on the very bottom of the screen (above the bottomnavbar).
I added `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to the column, but it seems like the `Column` in the `SingleChildScrollView` is shrinking to fit. How can I make `_BottomOne`  all the way on the bottom?

```dart
Column(children: [
        _StayOnTopWidget(),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                _FirstOne(),
                _BottomOne(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expanded` widget should be the parent of `_BottomOne`, which will take remaining space will align itself at the bottom

```
Column(children: [
        _StayOnTopWidget(),
        SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                _FirstOne(),
            Expanded(
                child: 
                  _BottomOne(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        )
      ]),
```

Comment: That works, but it pushes the bottomOne to under/behind the bottomnavbar

Comment: Add margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50) to _BottomOne(), incrase bottom margin as per your need. If works mediaQuery for better use